# Access Sourceforge Git via Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, sourceforge, github-desktop

As the title, I clone a project which host on SourceForge(SF). But when I use Github Desktop to commit code to SF, a error appear
`The repository doesn't seem to exist anymore. You may not have access, or it may have been deleted or renamed`
.That project is private, I can only commit when I use Git Shell and enter SF password. Is there anyway for me to use Github Desktop?

[Solved] After few hours, I have the solution. What I need is just add my public ssh key to sourceforge in this [Link](https://sourceforge.net/auth/shell_services). Normally, Github Desktop created ssh key if you loged in at least one. Just open %UserProfile%\.ssh\github_rsa.pub copy the plain text and paste into the above link. On linux it storages in `~/.ssh/` , find the *.pub file. Unfortunately, there is no *.pub file, just create ssh key with command `ssh-keygen` and then `ssh-add "LinkToPrivateSshKey"` (which does not contant `.pub`)
Some usefull link: [Github Doc](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) , [SF Doc](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/SSH%20Keys/)

Thanks for all supports, sorry because I can't close my question.

Comment: Please don't add "[Solved]" or similar to your title, and please don't edit the answer into your question. Instead, please [accept the answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that helped you the most. (If you found the answer yourself, you can even [self answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question.) If you have enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) any answers that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop/) for GitHub Desktop:

> You can add any Git repository to GitHub Desktop, even if it's not a GitHub repository.
>
> **1.** In the top left corner of the app, click +.
>
> **2.** At the top of the menu, click Add.
>
> **3.** Click Browse and, using Windows Explorer, navigate to the local repository you want to add.
>
> **4.** Click Add repository.

If your cloned project is already pointing to a SourceForge remote repository, then the above steps should be all you need to add the repository to GitHub Desktop.  GitHub Desktop will "know" where to send your push, pull, etc. commands when you do them.

Comment: yes, I already add it, the problem is when I commit. When I use Git shell to push, i must enter sourceforge's password. With GithubDesktop it can't do it, just say the repository was delte or i may not have access

Comment: Do _any_ functions work using GitHub Desktop on your branch from the SourceForge clone?

Comment: Nothing, i try create new branch, the result is the same. Maybe the prolem causes access Read/Write is SSH. Like this `git clone ssh://saitdev@git.code.sf.net/p/....`

Comment: Yes, you may need to change your Git configuration settings.

Comment: well, i don't know how to add sourceforge's ssh key for githubdesktop, also i can't enter ssh password on githubdesktop